# Do I need a work permit or non lucrative visa for Spain if I am only going to be there less than a month?

Tags: visa, working-visas, spain

My place of work offers a remote work program and I'd like to take advantage of this opportunity and travel to Spain for a minimum of 3 weeks or maximum of 4 weeks. I do plan on working some of the time while I am in Spain. While in Spain, I will be working for a US-based company and collecting a US salary and paying US taxes. Do I need a work permit or a non lucrative visa in my situation?